# how to make navigation bar centered with all styles on it using display: inline-block?

Tags: css

I am having trouble using inline-block property to make the navigation bar 
centered with the styles on it like color, width, padding. My main goal was to make nav centered with text aligned.

```
.nav { position: fixed;
top: 0 ;
left: 0;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center; 
color: white;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
width: 100%;
height: 42px;



}
.nav ul li { display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}


}
.nav ul li a { 
text-decoration: none;
padding: 12px 54px;
color: white;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give it a width you might use margin: 0 auto.

Check this [complete guide on centering](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav { position: fixed;
   top: 0 ;
   left: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center; 
   color: white;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   width: 100%;
   height: 42px;

}
.nav ul li { display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
}

.nav ul li a { 
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 12px 54px;
   color: white;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Don't post code in answer. Else Edit your post and add.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a working demo with all your code?

`inline-block` can be centered if you use `align-center` in a parent div.

https://embed.plnkr.co/Hs4NJ8m0YTg5TDVfnwPT/